# HttpClient fails to post to web API

Tags: angular, post, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple Angular form which I want to post a `Loan` object to a .net core web API.

After submitting the form I can see this data in the console:

> Object { Id: 0, BorrowerName: "asd", RepaymentAmount: 11.5, FundingAmount: 10 }

But my API action never gets called.

What am I doing wrong?

**Api Action**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Loan>> Get()
{
    return _context.Loans;
}
```

**Loan.cs**

```
public class Loan
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BorrowerName { get; set; }
    public decimal RepaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal FundingAmount { get; set; }
}
```

**loan-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Loan } from '../loan';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loan-form',
  templateUrl: './loan-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loan-form.component.css']
})

export class LoanFormComponent implements OnInit {

  model = new Loan(0, "", 0, 0);

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setRepaymentAmount(event) {
    this.model.RepaymentAmount = event * 1.15;
  } 
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.model);
    var config = {
      headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
      }
    }
    this.http.post('http://localhost:1113/api/loans', this.model, config);
  }
}
```

**loan-form.component.html**

```
<div class="container">

  <h1>New Loan Form</h1>

  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #loanForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BorrowerName">Borrower Name</label>
      <input type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
            id="BorrowerName" 
            required
            [(ngModel)]="model.BorrowerName" name="BorrowerName"
            #spy>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="FundingAmount">Funding Amount</label>

        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="FundingAmount" required
          [(ngModel)]="model.FundingAmount" name="FundingAmount"
          (ngModelChange)="setRepaymentAmount($event)"
          #spy>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="RepaymentAmount">Repayment Amount</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="RepaymentAmount"
      [(ngModel)]="model.RepaymentAmount" name="RepaymentAmount" readonly>
      TODO: remove this: {{model.RepaymentAmount}}
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!loanForm.form.valid">Submit</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing "subscription" for the post request.

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:1113/api/loans', this.model, config).subscribe();
```

Comment: This seems to have worked but I now have another [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53686395/allowanymethod-works-for-some-api-calls-but-not-for-others)

Answer (score 1):

Anything with Observable should be subscribed to make your request works,

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:1113/api/loans', this.model, config).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```